# Pass variable into SELECT portion of query

Tags: shell, variables, select

Say I have this from my shell script:

```
label="SOME_VALUE"
data_rec=`sqlplus -s ${user}/${password} << "EOF"
  set heading off feedback off verify off timing off
 SELECT load||','||fmt_load
 FROM (SELECT RETRIEVE_PROCESS_CONTROL('$label','','MMDDYYYY') load
       FROM dual),
      (SELECT RETRIEVE_PROCESS_CONTROL('$label','','MM/DD/YYYY-HH24:MI:SS') fmt_load
       FROM dual);
    exit
EOF`

load=`echo $data_rec | cut -f1 -d',' | awk '{print $1}'`
fmt_load=`echo $data_rec | cut -f2 -d',' | awk '{print $1}'`

printf "Load: $load\n"
printf "FMT: $fmt_load\n"
```

The variable substitution works if it is in the WHERE portion, but here, I need it in the SELECT portion.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your heredoc `<< "EOF"` doesn't expand the variables.  Remove the double quotes around the end marker `EOF` so that the variables are expanded:

```
data_rec=`sqlplus -s ${user}/${password} << EOF
...
```